# file upload default path

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I use File Upload in my application for upload an image file , but when i confirm image URL , but i have an error

this is error message :

> the file 'c:\program Files(x86)\IIS Express\filename.jpg' is missing

how i change dafault path ?

Here is my code in aspx file :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="browse" runat="server" Enabled="false" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" ></asp:FileUpload>
```

in code behind 
i make just

```
browse.FileName
```

Comment: you need to write file in a folder in your application directory

Comment: Please show a little more code in order to provide a [mcve]. Also, a web application usually does not have permission to write/save to program files folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are missing is Server.MapPath.

Below is the sample code which suggests how to use the FileUpload control.

It also has additional validations (they may not be required for you but keeping them here for understanding purpose).

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            {
                if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                }
                else
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 kb!";
            }
            else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```